# How to connect WInform to Webform in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, webforms, connect

When I click on a button in 'winform' then shows 'webform'

like:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 f2 = new Form2();
            f2.ShowDialog();

        }
```

or:

[image]

[image]

Comment: in VS2019 .net 4

Comment: It is really a trick question, as a WinForms app usually does not tie to a WebForms app. You can open a web browser in that button click event to open the web page you like, or host a `WebBrowser` control to load that page. Again, there might be an answer, only if you are more specific on what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually your code is defiantly correct for opening an another form with dialog but if you want to open a page of a website use this code

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
            frm2.Show();
            linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
        }
        private void VisitLink()
        {
            linkLabel1.LinkVisited = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.microsoft.com");
        }

        private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
        {
            VisitLink();
        }
```